# Could not convert string to float Error when plotting Categorical Values. Works on one computer and not the next?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot some categorical variables using Matplotlib. A relatively simple task I thought. However, when I use this script on one machine it works fine, and plots as expected. Yet, when I use another machine, I get the error ***could not convert string to float: 'C'***

Am I missing something here? Both machines are running Windows and using Python 3.6. However, the machines in which it works are running Windows 10, and the other machine which it isn't working is running Windows 7. Not sure of the significance of that..

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# Data Generate
data = pd.DataFrame()

for loc in ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']:
    for m in range(0,10,1):
        tfrom = m
        tto = m + 1
        code = random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'])

        data = data.append({'loc':loc, 't_from':tfrom, 't_to':tto, 'code':code},
                           ignore_index = True)


# Plot the Data
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,len(data['loc'].unique()), figsize = (15,10), sharey = True, num = 1)

i = 0
for siid in data['loc'].unique():

    y1 = data.loc[data['loc'] == siid, 't_from'].copy()
    y2 = data.loc[data['loc'] == siid, 't_to'].copy()
    x = data.loc[data['loc'] == siid, 'code'].copy()
    ax[i].plot((x,x), (y1,y2), lw = 4)
    ax[i].set_title(siid)
    ax[i].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
    i = i + 1

ax[0].invert_yaxis()
ax[0].legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: One of your machines uses matplotlib 2.1 the other some version <= 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I did miss something. I was using a slightly older version of Matplotlib (1.9). I updated to 2.1.0 and works fine.

Comment: There has never been a version 1.9 of matplotlib.

Comment: Oops.. Well it was an older version prior to my update.